# How to import this packages? Relative import in python3.3

Tags: python, import, relative-path, relative-import

I'm trying to make [this](https://chemlab.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graphics.html) work on my machine (arch, using gnome 3). I think that the setup went OK (I replaced all the print commands) but when I run `chemlab` on terminal I get an error telling me that there is no core package:

```
[yotam@Standing chemlab-master]$ chemlab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/chemlab", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('chemlab==0.2', 'chemlab')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 505, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1246, in run_script
    exec(compile(open(script_filename).read(), script_filename, 'exec'), namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/chemlab-0.2-py3.3-linux-i686.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/chemlab", line 4, in <module>
    import chemlab as cl
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/chemlab-0.2-py3.3-linux-i686.egg/chemlab/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from core.molecule import Molecule, Atom
ImportError: No module named 'core'
[yotam@Standing chemlab-master]$ ls /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/chemlab-0.2-py3.3-linux-i686.egg/chemlab/
__init__.py  contrib/     db/          io/          libs/        resources/   
__pycache__/ core/        graphics/    ipython.py   molsim/      utils/       
[yotam@Standing chemlab-master]$ ls /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/chemlab-0.2-py3.3-linux-i686.egg/chemlab/
```

So I tried to run the files locally. I went to the appropriate folder and run `python __init__.py` No I get

```
[yotam@Standing chemlab]$ python __init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from core.molecule import Molecule, Atom
  File "/home/yotam/Applications/Chemlab/chemlab-master/chemlab/core/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .molecule import Molecule, Atom
  File "/home/yotam/Applications/Chemlab/chemlab-master/chemlab/core/molecule.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..libs.ckdtree import cKDTree
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
[yotam@Standing chemlab]$
```

I searched a little and found that I can (should?) replace `..libs.ckdtree import cKDTree` with `chemlab.libs.ckdtree import cKDTree` I did so only to get

> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "./core/**init**.py", line 1, in 
> > >           from .molecule import Molecule, Atom
> > >         File "./core/molecule.py", line 6, in 
> > >           from chemlab.libs.ckdtree import cKDTree
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/chemlab-0.2-py3.3-linux-i686.egg/chemlab/**init**.py", line 1, in 
> > >           from core.molecule import Molecule, Atom
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name Molecule

Which baffle me. How can I import/run this?

Edit: folder structure:

```
chemlab
|
|
+  __init__.py
+  core
   |
   |
   +  molecule.py
```

Edit 2:
`chemlab/__init__.py` only line is
    from core.molecule import Molecule, Atom

and chelab/core/molecule/ import section looks like

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
from copy import copy

from ..libs.ckdtree import cKDTree
from ..db import ChemlabDB
cdb = ChemlabDB()

masses = cdb.get("data", "massdict")

from .attributes import MArrayAttr, MField
from .fields import AtomicField, FieldRequired
from .serialization import data_to_json, json_to_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency. But it's caused by your `chemlab.__init__.py` wanting to import `core.molecule.Molecule`, which it should not try to do. Remove that import line.

Comment: Importing ``Molecule`` and ``Atom`` is the only line in ``chemlab.__init__.py``. Please see my edit. I think that the circular  depenecies rise because I place the ``chemlab`` instead of ``..`` in the import section of molecule.py. This called the installed version of chemlab instead of the local.

Comment: Yes, it's the only line: but it's an unnecessary line. Remove it.

Comment: But... if I remove it, how do I start the program?

Comment: Well, not like that. Create a separate file, called something like `main.py`, and do the imports there.

Comment: When I call ``..libs`` I also call the ``__init__.py`` in the parent folder?